# Finding the line integral of a path in a cube

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I want to consider a continuous closed path $\alpha(t)$, which is drawn over the edges of a cube in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and passes through the points $(0, 0, 0)$ and $(3, 3, 3)$ (these last two points are vertices of the cube).
We have that the given vector field is $f:\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ given by $f(x, y, z)=(-y, x, z)$

We must parameterize then this path, we can take the following path

From $(0, 0, 0)$ to $(0, 0, 3)$ to $(0, 3, 3)$ to $(3, 3, 3)$, then parameterizing each line segment we have

$$\alpha_{1}=[(0, 0, 0) +t(0, 0, 3)]$$
$$\alpha_{2}=[(0, 0, 3) +t(0, 3, 3)]$$
$$\alpha_{3}=[(0, 3, 3) +t(3, 3, 3)]$$

So that the final path is the sum of the previous ones, i.e. $\alpha(t)=[(3t, 3+6t, 6+9t)]$, so we can find the line integral

$$\int f \cdot d\alpha= \int_{0}^{3} f[(3t, 3+6t, 6+9t)] \cdot (3, 6, 9)=\int_{0}^{3} (-3-6t, 3t, 6+9t) \cdot (3, 6, 9) =\frac{999}{2}$$

It may be that the parameterization is not the right one, as I feel that for some values of $t$ the points are outside the cube, any suggestions?

Comment: Easier if you do three separate line integrals, each over one of these three edges. Then you don't have to figure out why what you tried is wrong.

Comment: @EthanBolker Each of the line integrals comprises the segments you indicate, right?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. You correctly parameterized (with $t$ going from $0$ to $1$) three edges of the cube that in successtion go from the origin to the far corner at $(3,3,3)$.. (Earlier in the question you wrote vertices of the cube in four dimensions ...)

Comment: @EthanBolker You're right, I made a typing mistake.

Comment: @EthanBolker What I mean by my question is, should I calculate the line integral of $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \alpha_{3}$?

Comment: Yes. Think about what the line integral means and you'll see that. You don't add the paths - you add the integrals from each part of the path.

Comment: Closed path! What is the actual question? We can get different values for the line integral depending on the closed path. P.S. Adding the paths is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From $(0, 0, 0)$ to $(0, 0, 3)$ to $(0, 3, 3)$ to $(3, 3, 3)$, then parameterizing each line segment we have
>
> $$\alpha_{1}=[(0, 0, 0) +t(0, 0, 3)]\\\alpha_{2}=[(0, 0, 3) +t(0, 3, 3)]\\\alpha_{3}=[(0, 3, 3) +t(3, 3, 3)]$$
>
> So that the final path is the sum of the previous ones, i.e. $\alpha(t)=[(3t, 3+6t, 6+9t)]$,

Nope. This is a straight line intercepting $\def\<{\langle}\def\>{\rangle}\<0,0,0\>$ at $t=0$ and $\<3,9,15\>$ at $t=1$.

You require the path to zig-zag to the relevant vertices at $t=1$, $t=2$, and $t=3$.

Thus the path is a piecewise function: $$\begin{align} \alpha(t)&=\begin{cases}\<0,0,0\>+t\<0,0,3\>&:&t\in[0,1)\\\<0,0,3\>+(t-1)\<0,3,0\> &:& t\in[1,2)\\\<0,3,3\> + (t-2)\<3,0,0\> &:& t\in[2,3] \\\text{undef}&:&\text{elsewhen}\end{cases}\\[1ex]&=\begin{cases}\<0,0,3t\>&:&t\in[0,1)\\\<0,3t-3,3\> &:& t\in[1,2)\\\<3t-6,3,3\> &:& t\in[2,3] \\\text{undef}&:&\text{elsewhen}\end{cases}\\[2ex]\dfrac{\mathrm d \alpha}{\mathrm d t}&=\begin{cases}\<0,0,3\> \hspace{17ex}&:& t\in[0,1)\\\<0,3,0\> &:& t\in[1,2)\\\<3,0,0\> &:& t\in[2,3]\\\text{undef} &:& \text{elsewhen}\end{cases}\end{align}$$